# Why would I create a table using two steps?

Tags: sql-server, database, rdbms

Is there any use in creating a table and giving it default values in 2 steps? First with CREATE TABLE, then with ALTER TABLE for each column.Is is just matter of formatting preference? Or is there some more technical reason for doing this?

We have some create table scripts at my place defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_EXISTING](
    [SYS_ID] [varchar](17) NULL,
    [TYPE] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [CODE] [varchar](12) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TMG_ITS_PROF_INST_REC_T] ADD  DEFAULT (space((17))) FOR [SYS_ID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TMG_ITS_PROF_INST_REC_T] ADD  DEFAULT (space((35))) FOR [TYPE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TMG_ITS_PROF_INST_REC_T] ADD  DEFAULT (space((12))) FOR [CODE]
GO
```

Why or why shouldn't I go ahead and create new tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_NEW](
    [SYS_ID] [varchar](17) NULL DEFAULT space(17),
    [TYPE] [varchar](35) NULL DEFAULT space(35),
    [CODE] [varchar](12) NULL DEFAULT space(12)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can definitely use the "inline" style of creating the default constraint right with the table. I actually prefer it that way, because in my opinion, it makes it *clearer* which bits belong together - but at the same time, the table definition becomes a bit more involved and more complex.

**BUT** I would always recommend to **name** your constraints!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_NEW]
(
    [SYS_ID] [VARCHAR](17) NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_TableNew_SysId DEFAULT space(17),
    [TYPE] [VARCHAR](35) NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_TableNew_Type DEFAULT space(35),
    [CODE] [VARCHAR](12) NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_TableNew_Code DEFAULT space(12)
)
```

because if you ever need to deal with a constraint (to disable or drop it), unless you've named it explicitly, it will have a nice, quite counter-intuitive system-provided name and that typically causes headaches and troubles. **Name** your constraints!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer it all being done at once, in the create script.  I assume the alters were added after the table was initially created.  The scripts were kept separate so all environments can be updated as they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server management studio seems to generate table creation change scripts this way, perhaps thats why they are in this format:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
    (
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Surname nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_Table_1_Name DEFAULT N'Foo' FOR Name
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_Table_1_Surname DEFAULT N'bar' FOR Surname
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```